# Hermitian matrix has a symmetric spectrum if and only if $\lambda_1=\lambda_n$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

I seem to remember a result claiming that an (irreducible) zero-diagonal $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $H$ with entries $h_{ij}\in \{z\in\mathbb{C}~:~ |z|=1\}\cup\{0\}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n$ with the property that $\lambda_1=-\lambda_n$ if and only if $\lambda_{1+j}=-\lambda_{n-j}$ for all $j=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, but a source eludes me. Does this sound familiar to anyone or have I dreamt it?

Comment: What do you mean by $H\in \{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|=1\} $ ? The entries of $H$ are either $0$ or of absolute value $1$ ?

Comment: Apologies, I corrected the definition of $H$. It's simply a Hermitian matrix whose entries are either complex units or zero; nothing fancy.

Comment: $4\times 4$ case is obvious. So the first posiible test can be performed on $5\times 5$ matrix.